# Mouse events on each <g> tag of svg loaded on the material in threejs

Tags: javascript, css, svg, three.js, jquery-selectors

I am loading SVG images on to the mesh basic material of BoxBufferGeometry(cube) using SVGLoader. I want to trigger mouse events when user hovers/clicks on specific element of SVG which is loaded on the specific side of the cube.

I tried adding events into the .svg file before loading it but once it get loaded on the material it doesn\'t show any changes caused by the events.

Is there any other possible way to select the elements of loaded svg image and apply events on it?

For better understanding please refer http://plnkr.co/edit/YYN8aechHGTKXvPv6tOo?p=preview apart from this also tried to access the particular side using following code:

```
                raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );

                var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children );
                if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
                    var index = Math.floor( intersects[0].faceIndex / 2 );
                    if ( INTERSECTED != intersects[ 0 ].object && (index == 4 || index == 5)) {
                        if ( INTERSECTED ) {
                            INTERSECTED.material[intersects[0].faceIndex].color.setHex( INTERSECTED.currentHex );
                        }


                        INTERSECTED = intersects[ 0 ].object;
                        INTERSECTED.currentHex = INTERSECTED.material[4].color.getHex();
                        INTERSECTED.material[index].color.setHex( 0xCACACA );
                        f = index;
                }
```

Comment: I think this link can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451855/how-to-add-event-listeners-to-objects-in-a-svg

Comment: Also it is nice to add some sample code in the question.

Comment: When you apply the SVG as a texture, it's no longer an SVG. If you want to intersect the SVG, you'd need to get the UV position of the click on the cube face (which maps to an x,y position on the SVG), and determine which SVG tag was clicked based on that position.

Comment: @gusaindpk added sample link to the description. Hope this will make my question more clear

Comment: @MohitPatel created a plunker hope that will help.

Comment: @TheJim01 Thanks for your solution. I tried implementing the solution provided by you in my example(provided in plunker link). But I am facing a problem while zooming in or zooming out the object. The UV co-ordinates of specific object(for e.g circle in my case) sales with some indefinite proportion and the mapping of co-ordinates doesn't remains the same. Is there anyway around to get this proportion of change/scale in that specific object?

Comment: Hmm, zoom shouldn't have an effect on the UV found by the ray. But that question is different from the topic of this post. I recommend creating a new post to ask your new question, and remember to include as much detail and code as you can. :)

Comment: Hey @TheJim01 I have posted a new question. Can you please have a look at it. Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45174879/finding-uv-coordinates-of-a-point-on-material-rendered-on-3d-cube-in-threejs . Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I have used **threex.domevent.js** to capture the **mouseover** event and created a plunker. I am finding the cube face which has the svg image.
Links:
[detect mouse click / hover event on sides of cube in three js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29329634/detect-mouse-click-hover-event-on-sides-of-cube-in-three-js) **and**
https://github.com/jeromeetienne/threex.domevents.

- Attach the dom event using *threex.domevent.js**

  `domEvents  = new THREEx.DomEvents(camera, renderer.domElement)`
- Listen to mouse over event and find the face you require.

  ```
          domEvents.addEventListener(mesh, 'mouseover', function(event) {
          var vector = new THREE.Vector3(
              (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1, -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1, );
          vector.unproject(camera);
          raycaster.set(camera.position, vector.sub(camera.position).normalize());

          var intersects = raycaster.intersectObject(mesh);
          if (intersects.length > 0) {
              var index = Math.floor(intersects[0].faceIndex / 2);
              if (index === 4) {
                  //index 4 is  cude face having the svg image,
                  //you can load a new svg or do required things here
                  console.log('##############');
                  mesh.material[4].map = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('sample2.svg');
              }

          }
      }, false)
  ```

  Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/QXwqN3X70ex3EZmlKhRf?p=preview
  Hope it helps.

Comment: @MohitPatel did it help?

Comment: thanks for the solution but I am already able to perform the same task using my code. I wanted to trigger events on the sub-geometries(circle, star,...) of the shape and change the color of those particular sub-geometry.

Comment: OK will look into it

Comment: I think its not possible to attach events to svg itself as @TheJim01 has mentioned in comments. you also can check the link http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2013/04/30/closing-the-gap-between-html-and-webgl/.One possible way to enhance the code to find the particular circular area coordinates and check if mouse is present there and load other svg with the change sub-geometries

Comment: Yeah the approach provided by @TheJim01 is the best so far I have received. Trying to implement the same in  my code.

Comment: I will also have a look how to do it.